# How to do 1.5x scaling for pixel art where only one dimension has to scale?

Tags: scale, pixel-art

[image: Shades of green indicate the area that green can be deformed to fill, yellow indicates area that I don't know what to do with.]I'm working on a point and click adventure game where the top third of the screen is a 16:3 single piece background with sprites on top. The width has to be edge to edge. It can't be cropped because the screen doesn't move.

The bottom of the screen will be one where you can interact with objects. Think Papers, Please. It can be any dimension, it can be 16:6 for 16:9 screens and 16:9 for 4:3(16:12). The objects on the bottom screen can be scaled imperfectly so say a notebook that is 64x64 on 720p can be 2x scaled to 128x128 on 1080p. It will only be compared to other 2x scaled objects so it won't look out of place.

Shades of green indicate areas where light green can be stretched to fill, orange indicates the area that I don't know what to do with. Black can't be scaled 2x because it wouldn't fit and it can't be cropped.

Am I still forced to make 2 different sets of art if I want it to look right?

Comment: Try to mock-up the screen at each resolution you want to target, using the same placeholder assets. That will give you a clear idea which one is your toughest case to make work. Then you can share that example as part of your question to help focus answers on solving that problem.

Answer (score 3):

So I figured it out. I imagine this is common knowledge but I couldn't find it so I'll leave it here. The solution for me is to make people fit in 32x32, everything else scales relative to humans. Upscale that 2x for 720p and 3x for 1080p.